# No query results for model [App\Tournament] in Middleware SubstituteBindings

Tags: laravel

I recently get this error. I debugged it, and it doesn't not even enter my index method.

So, I guess from the log, it is a SubstituteBindings, but I don't really know what's the problem...

Here is the log's exception:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model [App\Tournament]. 
in /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:311
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(801): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->firstOrFail()
#1 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(39): Illuminate\Routing\Router->substituteImplicitBindings(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#2 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(137): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#3 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#4 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(65): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(137): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#6 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(137): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#9 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(137): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#12 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(137): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#15 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(137): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#18 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(644): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#21 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(618): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(596): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(267): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/src/RemoteValidationMiddleware.php(53): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(137): Proengsoft\JsValidation\RemoteValidationMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/Debugbar.php(51): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(137): Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\Debugbar->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#30 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(137): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#33 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(33): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(149): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#36 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 /Users/julien/Documents/Proyectos/laravel/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 /Users/julien/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php(106): require('/Users/julien/D...')
#39 {main}
```

Code:

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getDeleted()
{
    $currentModelName = trans_choice('core.tournament', 2);

    if (Auth::user()->isSuperAdmin()) {
        $tournaments = Tournament::onlyTrashed()->with('owner')
            ->has('owner')
            ->orderBy('tournament.created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(config('constants.PAGINATION'));
    } else {
        $tournaments = Auth::user()->tournaments()->with('owner')
            ->onlyTrashed()
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(config('constants.PAGINATION'));
    }
    $title = trans('core.tournaments_deleted');
    return view('tournaments.deleted', compact('tournaments', 'currentModelName', 'title'));
}
```

Here is the route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']],
function () {
      Route::get('tournaments/deleted', 'TournamentController@getDeleted');
    });
```

And here are the routes:

```
+--------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
    | Domain | Method    | URI                                                                           | Name                       | Action                                                                     | Middleware                 |
    +--------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
    |        | POST      | tournaments                                                                   | tournaments.store          | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@store                            | web,auth,ownTournament     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tournaments                                                                   | tournaments.index          | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@index                            | web,auth                   |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tournaments/create                                                            | tournaments.create         | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@create                           | web,auth,ownTournament     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tournaments/deleted                                                           |                            | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@getDeleted                       | web,auth,ownTournament     |
    |        | POST      | tournaments/{tournamentId}/trees                                              | storeAllTree               | App\Http\Controllers\PreliminaryTreeController@store                       | web,auth                   |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tournaments/{tournamentSlug}/invite/{token}                                   |                            | App\Http\Controllers\ChampionshipController@create                         | web                        |
    |        | DELETE    | tournaments/{tournament}                                                      | tournaments.destroy        | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@destroy                          | web,auth,ownTournament     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tournaments/{tournament}                                                      | tournaments.show           | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@show                             | web,auth                   |
    |        | PUT|PATCH | tournaments/{tournament}                                                      | tournaments.update         | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@update                           | web,auth,ownTournament     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tournaments/{tournament}/edit                                                 | tournaments.edit           | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@edit                             | web,auth,ownTournament     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tournaments/{tournament}/invite                                               |                            | App\Http\Controllers\InviteController@create                               | web,auth                   |
    |        | POST      | tournaments/{tournament}/invite/{invite}/categories                           |                            | App\Http\Controllers\ChampionshipController@store                          | web                        |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tournaments/{tournament}/register                                             |                            | App\Http\Controllers\TournamentController@register                         | web                        |
    |        | POST      | tournaments/{tournament}/teams                                                | teams.store                | App\Http\Controllers\TeamController@store                                  | web,auth                   |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tournaments/{tournament}/teams                                                | teams.index                | App\Http\Controllers\TeamController@index                                  | web,auth                   |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tournaments/{tournament}/teams/create                                         | teams.create               | App\Http\Controllers\TeamController@create                                 | web,auth                   |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tournaments/{tournament}/teams/{team}                                         | teams.show                 | App\Http\Controllers\TeamController@show                                   | web,auth                   |
    |        | PUT|PATCH | tournaments/{tournament}/teams/{team}                                         | teams.update               | App\Http\Controllers\TeamController@update                                 | web,auth                   |
    |        | DELETE    | tournaments/{tournament}/teams/{team}                                         | teams.destroy              | App\Http\Controllers\TeamController@destroy                                | web,auth                   |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tournaments/{tournament}/teams/{team}/edit                                    | teams.edit                 | App\Http\Controllers\TeamController@edit                                   | web,auth                   |
    |        | POST      | tournaments/{tournament}/users                                                | tournament.users.store     | App\Http\Controllers\CompetitorController@store                            | web,auth                   |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tournaments/{tournament}/users                                                | tournament.users.index     | App\Http\Controllers\CompetitorController@index                            | web,auth                   |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tournaments/{tournament}/users/create                                         | tournament.users.create    | App\Http\Controllers\CompetitorController@create                           | web,auth                   |
    |        | DELETE    | tournaments/{tournament}/users/{user}                                         | users.destroy              | App\Http\Controllers\CompetitorController@destroy                          | web,auth                   |
    |        | PUT|PATCH | tournaments/{tournament}/users/{user}                                         | tournament.users.update    | App\Http\Controllers\CompetitorController@update                           | web,auth                   |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tournaments/{tournament}/users/{user}                                         | tournament.users.show      | App\Http\Controllers\CompetitorController@show                             | web,auth                   |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tournaments/{tournament}/users/{user}/edit                                    | tournament.users.edit      | App\Http\Controllers\CompetitorController@edit                             | web,auth                   |
    +--------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], 
function () {

    Route::resource('tournaments', 'TournamentController', ['names' => ['index' => 'tournaments.index', 'show' => 'tournaments.show', 'create' => 'tournaments.create', 'edit' => 'tournaments.edit', 'store' => 'tournaments.store', 'update' => 'tournaments.update']]);
    Route::resource('/tournaments/{tournament}/teams', 'TeamController', ['names' => ['index' => 'teams.index', 'create' => 'teams.create', 'edit' => 'teams.edit', 'store' => 'teams.store', 'update' => 'teams.update']]);
    Route::get('testtesttest/deleted', 'TournamentController@getDeleted');


    Route::resource('tournaments/{tournament}/users', 'CompetitorController', ['names' => ['index' => 'tournament.users.index', 'show' => 'tournament.users.show', 'create' => 'tournament.users.create', 'edit' => 'tournament.users.edit', 'store' => 'tournament.users.store', 'update' => 'tournament.users.update']]);
    Route::delete('tournaments/{tournamentId}/categories/{championshipId}/users/{userId}/delete', 'CompetitorController@deleteUser');
    Route::put('tournaments/{tournamentId}/categories/{championshipId}/users/{userId}/confirm', 'CompetitorController@confirmUser');
    Route::get('tournaments/{tournament}/invite', 'InviteController@create');
});
```

Any idea what could it be???? Before, it was working great!

Comment: `No query results for model [App\Tournament]` -- there aren't any results. What's the problem?

Comment: I have no firstOrFail in my code

Comment: Maybe if you posted the code we would know that.

Comment: thing is as I say in the post, this error is not even getting into my code...

Comment: But I can show any part of the code, but the controller is not worth, because dd in the first line is not executed

Comment: You said it was working great before.  Before what exactly?  Something must have changed.

Comment: lol, yep, I don't when exactly. A lot of thing have changed, since I migrate 5.3. I don't know what changed, and my problem is I don't really know how to debug it

Comment: I'm guessing you're using route-model binding. The third line of the error `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder->firstOrFail()` is telling you that it's not finding any `Tournament` with whatever route parameter you're trying to load. i.e. if you're trying to load /tournaments/10 and there is no tournament with id 10, you'll get this error.

Comment: I don't pass any argument in my method :( I will publish it even if it doesn't enter inside.)

Comment: question edited

Comment: Also post the part of your routes file for for this method along with the URL you're trying to access.

Comment: Did you migrate from 5.2 to 5.3 and that's when this broke?

Comment: Yes, I migrated, but I'm not sure if the migration broke it, or when did it break

Comment: The Route is posted!

Comment: From the command line do `php artisan route:list` and post the `tournament/*` routes.

Comment: Published list of routes

Comment: Change `Route::get('tournaments/deleted', 'TournamentController@getDeleted');` to `Route::get('testtesttest/deleted', 'TournamentController@getDeleted');` and go to `/testtesttest/deleted`, see if that fixes the problem. If so you probably just need to rearrange your routes file.

Comment: it worked, now it is entering the controller. Can you explain what's happening??? don't understand

Comment: Go ahead and post the other routes relating to `tournaments` from your routes file in your question and we'll get this figured out.

Comment: I already did that... Or what do you mean?

Comment: I'm assuming there's something in your route file like `Route::resource('tournaments', 'TournamentController');`? Post that part along with the other part that you already posted.

Comment: Your routes conflict with each other - `tournaments/deleted` and `tournaments/{tournament}`. I think it's basically calling `Tournament::findOrFail('deleted')`

Comment: I published the web.php. Does it help???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Supplementing Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers).

If you're using a resource controller in your routes file, any additional routes need to come before that.

In your case, you'll need to do:

```
// supplemental/additional routes first
Route::get('tournaments/deleted', 'TournamentController@getDeleted');

// then the resource
Route::resource('tournaments', 'TournamentController', ['names' => ['index' => 'tournaments.index', 'show' => 'tournaments.show', 'create' => 'tournaments.create', 'edit' => 'tournaments.edit', 'store' => 'tournaments.store', 'update' => 'tournaments.update']]);
```

This prevents the router from trying to load `tournaments/deleted` as the `tournaments.show` route with `deleted` being the tournament ID. With the `deleted` route before the resource controller, Laravel will match that route first if it can, then move on if not. In your case, it's matching to `tournaments/{tournament}` before ever getting to `tournaments/deleted`.

Answer (score 0):

**firstOrFail()**  is a method that if no rows match the given criteria, it throws a `ModelNotFound` exception.  Because this is happening in the routing, it suggests that Laravel is trying to inject a model into the route.  **I'm guessing your current URL either has an invalid Tournament id or is missing one altogether**.  When Laravel reaches a [required route parameter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#required-parameters) it'll fail in this instance.

Comment: Added route definition, I have no param in URL :(

Comment: Are you sure you have no other routes conflicting and/or overriding this one?  Everything about this says it's failing during route binding substitution.

Comment: Published list of routes